# bash Function output to email without format change

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I wrote a function(elb_detail) in my shell script,when I execute the script in terminal i can see like below ..

> ## sds-freshservice
>
> ELB_HTTPCode_ELB_5XX.cfg : CONFIGURED
>
> ELB_RequestCount.cfg : CONFIGURED
>
> ELB_SpilloverCount.cfg : NOT CONFIGURED
>
> ELB_SurgeQueueLength.cfg : NOT CONFIGURED
>
> ELB_UnHealthyHostCount.cfg : NOT CONFIGURED`

But I wanted to send the script output to my mail , so used below in my shell script (tried by  passing the function output to variable and send email )

`output=$(elb_detail)
echo -n $output | mailx mymailid`

`**elb_detail is the function wrote in the script**`

I am receiving the email like below (everything as single line), but I wanted my email to display the output as mentioned above.

`################ sds-freshservice ################ ELB_HTTPCode_ELB_5XX.cfg : CONFIGURED ELB_RequestCount.cfg : CONFIGURED [31mELB_SpilloverCount.cfg : NOT CONFIGURED  [31mELB_SurgeQueueLength.cfg : NOT CONFIGURED  [31mELB_UnHealthyHostCount.cfg : NOT CONFIGURED`

Please help to guide on this
 ( as far as I understood it is not possible to get the desired output by passing the function output to the variable .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `echo` the captured output you lose all the newlines (and don't even add a trailing one due to `-n`), so why? Simply pipe the function's output into the mailer:

```
elb_detail | mailx mymailid
```

Comment: I tried but I am not getting any email `elb_detail | mailx mailid`
When I do bash -vx scriptname to see  for debugging , I am not even seeing the line `elb_detail | mailx mailid`getting executed

Comment: seems no email delivering to my mail box , let me check your suggestion and come back here